# How get high frequency words in index with specific filter?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to get high frequency words in specific index with special filter.
Library lucene-analysis-common has pre-built function getHighFreqTerms in HighFreqTerms class.

`HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(indexReader, resultCount, FieldName, comparator)`
but it's analyze the whole index.

In my case, I want get the most used words in different periods (last hour, week, month.. etc)

(LongField is already created as Date interpreter in ms)

Google-Searching and reading the sources of lucene - no results.

I have only one bad idea:
create different indexes for every period. for example:
WEEK_INDEX
MONTH_INDEX
DAY_INDEX
and create duplicates on every new document.